# Why is $\operatorname{rect}(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{w}) = \operatorname{rect}(w-\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: radicals, rectangles, change-of-variable

I have to determine the first order probability density function for $w(t, \epsilon)$, with the hypothesis that I have two statistically independent functions $x(t, \epsilon)$ and $y(t, \epsilon)$ uniformly distributed in $[-\frac12,\frac12]$.

$$
  w(t,\epsilon) = z^2(t,\epsilon)
  \quad\text{and}\quad
  z^2(t,\epsilon) = (x(t,\epsilon)+y(t,\epsilon))^2
$$

I set a $t$ for the evalutation, and $\epsilon$ is given, so my functions become random variable, defined this way:
$$
  W = Z^2 = (X+Y)^2
$$

For any variable I have a probability density like:
$p_x(x)$ for $x(t,\epsilon)$

So I can define that 
$p_z(z) = p_x(x) \cdot p_y(y)$.

Having $p_x(x) = \operatorname{rect}(x)$ and $p_y(y) = \operatorname{rect}(y)$, then $p_z(z) = \operatorname{tri}(z)$.

By having triangle as a result for $z$, I have to consider the $p_w(w)$ in two parts $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, +\infty)$, so in first part I got 
\begin{gather*}
  p_z(z) = (1+z)
           \cdot
           \operatorname{rect}\left( z + \frac{1}{2} \right), \\
  z_1 = -\sqrt{w}, \\
  p_z(z_1) = (1 - \sqrt{w})
             \cdot
             \operatorname{rect}\left( w - \frac{1}{2} \right).
\end{gather*}
With this assumptions, how can I say that:
$$
    \operatorname{rect}\left( \frac{1}{2} - \sqrt{w} \right)
  = \operatorname{rect}\left( w - \frac{1}{2} \right)
$$

Please, help me, I'm really going crazy.

Edit:
$\operatorname{rect}$ is the [rectangular function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function).

Comment: What is *rect*?

Comment: rect is the rectangular function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. What does $Z$ and $Z_1$ have to do with it? Is $w$ and $W$ the same thing? Are the variables real or complex? Etc.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Added complete problem.